# pgfplots doesn't draw the entire line

Tags: pgfplots

I was trying to plot my data and then draw a line of best fit through it. This was my attempt:

```latex
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymax=4000, ymin=0, xmin=0, xmax=110, axis lines=middle, xlabel=$Mass (g)$, ylabel=$Period (s)$, title={Our Data}]
            \addplot [only marks] table {
                10 2155.12368
                20 2821.48917
                50 3714.28038
                100 3086.27433
                70 3188.29439
                30 2820.53166
            };
            \addplot[color=blue, samples=180]{414.328*sqrt(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This yielded the following output:

[image: output]

Only a tiny part of the desired line is visible. Anyone know why? I don't think it is the scale of the graph because I have seen people graph at larger scales. What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Whilst there is enough code for this question to be answered probably, could you edit your question to make it compile please? As in, begin with `\documentclass{}` and finish with `\end{document}`. It means people do not need to guess at your class/packages and helps people help you, hope someone can answer!

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the domain of function to plot:

```
\addplot[color=blue, samples=180,domain=0:100]{414.328*sqrt(x)};
```

You have:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For future reference, what is the default value of the domain?

Comment: You have to add the domain like in my line of code.

Comment: Yes I did, and it worked. But, I was asking what the default value is. Basically, if I didn't specify the domain, then what would the default domain be? I am curious about this because it typically works without the domain, so I believe that I was working at a scale that was over the default domain range and I want to know where the cutoff is.

Comment: I think there is no default domain. xmin and xmax is only for axix draw. For points the domain is fixed by coordinates of points. For functions You have to specify the domain, for each function.